Как изменить ссылку в зависимости от значения переменной (Python)
Я хочу создать программу, и , в зависимости от значения, которое введет пользователь менять адрес ссылки. Сайт остается тем же, меняется только путь.
пример:
значение пользователя 1 - https://сайт.ру/1
значение пользователя 413 - https://сайт.ру/413

Вы имеете ввиду это?
addr = f"https://сайт.ру/{input()}"
print(addr)

